# Proper Collision

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

So basically im trying to figure out how to make a proper collision between two Rectangles.
Detecting isn't the problem, but the rectangles begin to clip. I wanted to reset the position, but how do I do that.
I'm trying to use dx and dy to reset, but it won't reset to the right coordinates.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU6sK.png (Sorry I can't use images yet)

```
System.out.println(this.y + this.h + " " +  e.getY());
if(this.y + this.h >= e.getY())
{
    if(this.dy > 0)
    {
        this.y -= delta * this.dy + 0.1; 
        this.dy = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.y += delta * this.dy;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.inAir = false;
    }
}
```

This code is just an example to show how I am trying it for the top. (this = the white Rectangle and e = the orange one) I used my class Entity, which extends Rectangle.

I'm checking intersection before I call this. This is a function in the "white" Entity and the intersection is checked in the update function of the main loop.

If I use this, there is like 1px between the rectangles.
Any ideas? 
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: No, because it wouldn't make sense. Maybe I should have added that. This is just for collision on top. So the white rectangle would just fall through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html

Use the `Rectangle` class.

#### Here, some code

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TzkST3Hm

Comment: I'm using them. I made the class Entity which extends Rectangle. The problem isn't the detection, but the resetting of the position.

Comment: Then just use `if (Entity1.intersects(Entity2)) { ... }`

Comment: If they intersect, set box 1's location to be directly on top of box 2. Something like `Box1.setXLocation(Box2.getXLocation - Box1.height);`

Comment: I agree.  Being greater than is not the same as intersecting.  Two points intersect when they are the same.  I think it's a good question.  Picklish, you should vote up. :D

Comment: derp. I'm using `org.newdawn.slick.Graphics`, isn't it the same? Because `intersects` of `awt.Rectangle` will not reset the position..

Comment: Well yes. I already tried that, but if I want to add collision from every side, how am I going to decide from which side the rectangles intersect?Like the 2. in this picture? [link](http://i.imgur.com/rFYnC.png) Because the red rectangle clips through, it could be from top or from the left..

Comment: Like this? http://i.imgur.com/8IVTk.png Oh wait, I misread your comment. You can check if it intersects, and if it does, don't let it move in that direction. Or you could move it back to its previous location.

Comment: You're checking collision every time BEFORE you move not after? Am I right with this. Because that could be the answer. I will test right now!

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 well... of course it does. There's no `main` method, no `class`, or anything, it's just pseudocode. Have you even looked at the errors?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do rectangular collision is to use the `Rectangle` class to detect collision using the `.intersects(Rectangle)` method, and then calculate a new variable called `displacementX` and `displacementY`.

`displacementX = Math.abs(entitiy1.getX() - entity2.getX());`

`displacementY = Math.abs(entitiy1.getY() - entity2.getY());`

So what we have currently is the amount of pixels `entity1` is intruding on `entity2` (or vice versa due to the absolute value).  Then, run some comparisons and move `entity1` (or `entity2`) by the value of the lesser `displacement`, which should yield perfect-looking collision.

This is at least how I do it.  The correct method for rectangular collision is to:

1) Determine if they collide

2) Correct it

3) Render

Simply preventing movement after detecting collision will look horrible (especially on low frame rates).

Hope I helped!

~Izman